# PostGIS retrieve polygons within a rectangle

Tags: postgis

I am building a system to bring in shapefile data from a PostGIS database and render it on top of OpenStreetMap tiles using the Leaflet.js library.

My table (sierra_county_parcels) has a polygon geometry field (geom) in SRID 4326, and a field called "upc" that contains the parcel ID. There are about 16,000 rows in sierra_county_parcels. What I need to do is retrieve all of the upc values for rows where the geom polygon is within the currently visible part of the Leaflet map control. I have already written the code to send the northwest and southeast lat/lon pairs and generate an SQL query, which looks like this:

```
SELECT upc AS pt_parcel_key
FROM  sierra_county_parcels
WHERE  ST_Within(geom, ST_Envelope(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOINT(33.167444534375925 -107.14931488037108, 33.08909661229697 -107.35513687133788)')))
```

The MULTIPOINT WKT is what I'm currently using to specify the corners (nw_latitude, nw_longitude, se_latitude, se_longitude).

The problem is that the query always returns 0 results. For this query, the map was zoomed out to show most of the region where the geometries should be.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

John W.

Comment: What if a polygon is not completely within your box and just a part of it is intersecting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your x's and y's are reversed. Longitude is X and comes first, Latitude is Y and comes second.

Comment: Ended up changing the query a bit to use the && operator and BOX3D too. But yes, my lat/longs were indeed switched. Thanks much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try using [ST_MakeEnvelope](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_MakeEnvelope.html) to make a box:

```
SELECT upc AS pt_parcel_key
FROM sierra_county_parcels
WHERE geom && ST_MakeEnvelope($long_min, $lat_min, $long_max, $lat_max, 4326);
```

(note: replace the `$` parameters with the appropriate value)